# Spring boot controller issue, getting whitelabel page error ,what might be wrong here?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have made projects before on spring and never got any issue like this before ,i just can't seem to figure out what is wrong here, all dependencies are correctly imported .

Here is how my vaultengine.java looks like :

VaultEngine.java :

```
package com.example.VaultEngine;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class VaultEngineApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(VaultEngineApplication.class, args);
}
@GetMapping("/h")
public String greetingForm() {
    return "index.html";
}
}
```

I am using a custom port cause i have 8080 in use somewhere already.
application.properties:

```
server.port=8989
```

All dependencies are properly loaded.
pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
  instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
   4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <version>1</version>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

 </project>
```

[image: pic]

[image]

Comment: share your index.html file location and its code. I think you may be misplaced your index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`, so

```java
    @GetMapping("/h")
    public String greetingForm() {
        return "index";
    }
```

and put `index.html` to `src/main/resources/templates/`.

refs:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/h")
    public String greetingForm() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why ? Looks like there is no need for rest specificities here.